# Copying and pasting specific files from one existing directory to another existing directory

Tags: r

Hi I am new to R and been trying to create a script that copies a few specific files from one location to another location. Both directories already exist.

```
#identify the folders
current.folder <-'S:\xx'
new.folder <-'S:\yy'
filestocopy<-c("a.xlsx",'b.xlsx','c.xlsm')

#copy the files
file.copy(filestocopy,new.folder)
```

Comment: Either `setwd(current.folder)` or `file.copy(paste(current.folder, filestocopy, sep = "\\"), new.folder)`

Comment: Thanks @Mako212. I ran it however console is blank and nothing is copied.
   '#identify the folders
    current.folder <-'S:\x'
    new.folder <-'S:\y'
    filestocopy<-c("a.xlsx",'b.xlsx','c.xlsm')

    #copy the files
    file.copy(paste(current.folder, filestocopy, sep = "\\"), new.folder)

Comment: You need double backslashes in the rest of your paths: `S:\\x` etc.

Comment: @Mako212 hi Mako, still doesnt seem to work once i added double backslashes into my paths. should i setwd at the beginning of my code? not sure what else is wrong.

Comment: @Mako212 hi. I figured it out. I deleted the # commands and it worked. I thought # allowed identification of what the codes is doing below similar to python?

Comment: `#` is the comment character in R. Deleting those shouldn't have had any effect, unless you had other characters that weren't on the comment line, that you also deleted.

Comment: This would be easy in dos (if windows) use the `cp` for copy and `move` to cut/paste.